# String.Split not working to get values

Tags: c#, regex, xml, string, split

I have an XML which is passes as a string variable to me. I want to get the value of specific tags from that XML. Following is the XML I have and what I'm trying to achieve:

```
<code>
string xmlData = @"  
<HEADER>
    <TYPE>AAA</TYPE>
    <SUBTYPE>ANNUAL</SUBTYPE>
    <TYPEID>12345</TYPEID>
    <SUBTYPEID>56789</SUBTYPEID>
    <ACTIVITY>C</ACTION>
</HEADER>";

var typeId = data.Split("<TYPEID>")[0];      //Requirement
var activity = data.Split("<ACTIVITY>")[0];  //Requirement
</code>
```

I know string.Split(); doesn't work here as it requires a single character only. Other alternate is to use regex which seems a bit threatening to me. Although I have tried to work with it but doesn't getting the desired result. Can someone help with the regex code?

Comment: Why can't you just parse XML, make it to an object?

Comment: I can't change the code. It's been passed as a string parameter to a method and I have to work with that variable. Tough luck :(

Comment: are `<ACTIVITY>` and `</ACTION>` the only tags that don't match?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You should have used XML Parsing to get the values but since you are trying split to split a string from a string and not char you can choose

```
string typeId = xmlData.Split(new string[] { "<TYPEID>" }, StringSplitOptions.None)[1];
string typeIdVal = typeId.Split(new string[] { "</TYPEID>" }, StringSplitOptions.None)[0];
```

and it looks very neat and clean with XML Parsing

```
XmlDocument xmlDoc= new XmlDocument(); 
xmlDoc.Load("yourXMLFile.xml"); 

XmlNodeList XTypeID = xmlDoc.GetElementsByTagName("TYPEID");
string TypeID = XTypeID[0].InnerText;
```

You can also choose SubString like

```
string typeidsubstr = xmlData.Substring(xmlData.IndexOf("<TYPEID>") + 8, xmlData.IndexOf("</TYPEID>") - (xmlData.IndexOf("<TYPEID>") + 8));
```

I used +8 because the length of `<TYPEID>` is 8 you can also choose it string.length to evaluate the result.

Comment: Yes with XML it can be a lot easier, but I cannot change the existing code. I have to inject the new functionality within that code. Thanks for the code, It worked like charm. :)

Comment: However using the first approach xmlData.Split() option gives "index was out of the bound" exception. Any thoughts on it?

Answer (score 1):

You can use XML Linq objects to parse these.

NB: There is a typo in the ACTIVITY element, the closing tag should be /ACTIVITY, not /ACTION! (I've corrected below)

```
string xmlData = @"<HEADER>
                <TYPE>AAA</TYPE>
                <SUBTYPE>ANNUAL</SUBTYPE>
                <TYPEID>12345</TYPEID>
                <SUBTYPEID>56789</SUBTYPEID>
                <ACTIVITY>C</ACTIVITY>
            </HEADER>";

            var doc = XDocument.Parse(xmlData);

            var typeId = doc.Root.Elements("TYPEID").First().Value;
            var activity = doc.Root.Elements("ACTIVITY").First().Value;
```